# Show more than 20 items in pages or posts edit dashboard

Tags: pages, screen-options

How can an admin display more than 20 items under "ALL posts" ( or on other pages )?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Go to `Screen Options` at the top, and change the number to something like 200. I don't think it will survive much more than that.

[image]

Comment: I would add that setting a high number seems especially problematic for hierarchical post types.

Comment: yes, that done the job.

Comment: Does not affect other users nor is it a programmatic solution. Screen options is not available and cannot be made available in certain cases/for certain user roles.